# How to GET search results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

So, I'm able to make a post request and see the search results however when I click refresh I get a missing get request error.

So, essentially, I'm un-able to GET my search results but I'm able to POST my search results. How might I accomplish this?

routes.rb:

```
  resources :statistics, except: :show do
      collection do
        post :search, as: 'statistics_search' 
      end
    end
```

Error:

```
Routing Error
No route matches [GET] "/admin/statistics/search"
```

Controller code (statistics_controller.rb)

```
class SaasAdmin::StatisticsController < SaasAdminController

  inherit_resources

  def index

  end

  def search
    @search = Search.new(params[:search])

    @impressions = Impression.where("impressionable_type = 'Clip' AND impressionable_id = ? AND impressions.created_at BETWEEN ? AND ?", @search.clip, @search.start_date, @search.end_date)
    render 'index'
  end

end
```

Thanks!

**Updated error**

```
NoMethodError in SaasAdmin::StatisticsController#search
undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass



  def initialize(params = {})
    params.each do |k, v| < --- this is what it's referring to.
      send("#{k}=", v)
    end
  end
```

**search.rb**

```
class Search < ActiveModel::Name
    attr_accessor :clip, :start_date, :end_date
  extend ActiveModel::Naming
  include ActiveModel::Conversion

  def initialize(params = {})
    params.each do |k, v|
      send("#{k}=", v)
    end
  end

    def start_date=(date)
        @start_date = Date.parse(date)
    end

  def end_date=(date)
    @end_date = Date.parse(date)
  end

  def persisted?
    false
  end
end
```

Comment: include the error also...\

Comment: Updated, with the error msg.

Comment: Can you post controller code?

Comment: Are you hitting refresh as in F5 or just selecting the URL and hitting Enter?

Comment: @MattGibson updated the controller code. Also, Tamer, I'm hitting the refresh button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We've created "GET" search functionality here: http://firststopcosmeticshop.co.uk

---

**GET**

You'll want to do the following:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :statistics, except: :show do
   match :search, as: 'statistics_search', on: :collection, via: [:get, :post]
end
```

---

**Model**

Something else to consider is how you're using your `Search` model.

I don't understand why you've included a separate `Search` model which does nothing more than populate attributes into an object? Surely you'll be better just passing your search params through to a [`class method`](http://www.railstips.org/blog/archives/2009/05/11/class-and-instance-methods-in-ruby/), allowing you to bring back an object formed from the data you want to view itself.

You'll get a better perspective of this from [this Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/37-simple-search-form)

[image]

We use this setup:

```
#app/models/impression.rb
class Impression < ActiveRecord::Base
   def self.search clip, start_date, end_date
      where("impressionable_type = 'Clip' AND impressionable_id = ? AND impressions.created_at BETWEEN ? AND ?", clip, start_date, end_date)
   end
end

#app/controllers/sass_admin/statistics_controller.rb
class SaasAdmin::StatisticsController < SaasAdminController
  inherit_resources

  def search
    @impressions = Impression.search params[:clip], params[:start_date], params[:end_date]
    render 'index'
  end

end
```

You'll be able to use a `form_tag` to support this:

```
#app/views/your_view.html.erb
<%= form_tag statistics_search_path do %>
   <%= text_field_tag :clip %>
   <%= text_field_tag :start_date %>
   <%= text_field_tag :end_date %>
   <%= submit_tag %>
<% end %>
```

--

**Third Party**

Of course, the above will only properly work for "searching" a single model, as you are.

If you wanted to extend this to multiple models, you'll want to use one of the "index" search plugins. These works by taking the data you stipulate & then "indexing" them (much the same way as Google), with which you'll be able to search through the indexed data.

You can see a [good Railscast about how to implement this functionality here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/278-search-with-sunspot)

If you want more information about this, I'll gladly update the answer

Comment: Thanks Rich, however, with this the date-range is no longer selectable on the :start_date, :end_date text fields. With the former way, when I would click the text field my JQuery date select would pop up. Can we still incorporate that funcitonality?

Answer (score 0):

Rails route will try to find matching both path **and** request method. So in other words `POST /path` and `GET /path`. In your case you have define both `get` and `post` routes or just user `match` method to allow any request method:

```
collection do
  match :search, as: 'statistics_search', via: [:get, :post]
end
```

More information: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#http-verb-constraints

UPDATE: Although above information is correct, it won't work with your code, because parameters of `POST` request are sent in a body, not the url. Remember that http is stateless protocol. Solution would be leaving `get :search` in routes and send form with `GET` method, so parameters are sent as part of url.

Comment: Thanks Lucas, although I've got an error from this, now when I click refresh I get the above error. We're certainly much closer now though.

Comment: Ah, I c - so what should the form url be then? As currently it's: <%= form_for Search.new, url: statistics_search_saas_admin_statistics_path do |f| %>

Comment: Path is fine, you need to change method: ```<%= form_for Search.new, url: statistics_search_saas_admin_statistics_path, method: :get do |f| %>```. Remember that routes match both method and path. More information on form_for method: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_for

Comment: Thanks, we're about 90% there :) I'm still getting the same error as above with the params.each though, even after updating the form_for, happy to do a TW session if needed.